# How to stop the event propagation from the view

Tags: android

I have two View add in my layout: the `mapContainer` and the `PoiView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:pv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.app.ui.view.PoiView
        android:id="@+id/poiView"
        android:visibility="invisible" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></com.app.ui.view.PoiView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now  the `mapContainer` will take the whole space of the screen except the action bar and the `poiView` will be be visible and overlapped at the top of `mapContainer` if I click somewhere in the `mapContainer`.

However I found that if I click the `poiView` the views inside the `mapContainer` will receive also, it seems that the `poiView` propagate the event to the `mapConatiner`.

Is it possible to stop this ?